# Hibernate, many to one, update

Tags: java, hibernate

my entities:

```
@Entity
public class Film {
    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
    private long filmId;

    @ManyToOne
    private Category category;
    //... 
}

@Entity
public class Category implements Comparable {
    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    private String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "category")
    private List<Film> films;
    // ...
}
```

When I try to modify record:

```
filmBo.updateFilm(lastEdited);
```

Everything works ok, I may change film title, duration, but I can't change category... why ?

@EDIT
yes, Film and Category have Entity annotation.

```
public void updateFilm(Film film) {
    getHibernateTemplate().update(film);
}
```

after that, I correctly changed film name and duration, only category was old (not changed)

Category

```
                <h:selectOneMenu value="#{c.category.name}" rendered="#{c.editable}">
                    <f:selectItems value="#{category.getCategoriesList()}" var ="cat"
                                   itemLabel="#{cat.name}" 
                                   itemValue="#{cat.name}"/>
                </h:selectOneMenu>

                <h:outputText value="#{c.category.name}" rendered="#{not c.editable}" />
            </h:column>

            <h:column>

                <f:facet name="header">Action</f:facet>

                <h:commandLink value="Edit" action="#{film.editAction(c)}" 
                               rendered="#{not c.editable}" />

            </h:column>
```

Comment: I take it `Film` is annotated `@Entity` as well? Plus, please show the code where you're trying to change `Film.category` and the way `updateFilm` persists/merges/updates the entity.

Comment: Are you trying to select a new `Category` for a film or are you  trying to change the category's name?

Comment: yes, in addition:     System.out.println("AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA  + lastEdited.getCategory().getName()); from saveAction() write new category, but after update  i have still old category

Comment: I just realized my answer is only relevant if your entities are not managed, my bad. So.. How do you load your `Film` entity and do you get a new Session inside `getHibernateTemplate()`? Also, have you checked Hibernate doesn't generate an `UPDATE` for the category? It might be updated in the database w/o being shown in the frontend.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not quite believing you really *intend* to *just* change the category name. But your problem is caused by Hibernate only updating the entity you tell it to update. For it to process other (changed) entities, you need to tell it to, like so:

```
@Entity
public class Film {
    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
    private long filmId;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = { CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE })
    private Category category;
    //... 
}
```

---

**Edit:** Since you just want to switch the entity, you need to change your xhtml, too:

```
<h:selectOneMenu value="#{c.category}" rendered="#{c.editable}">
    <f:selectItems value="#{category.categoriesList}" var ="cat"
                   itemLabel="#{cat.name}" />
    <f:converter converterId="omnifaces.SelectItemsIndexConverter" />
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

Since your value is now an object, you need a converter. I'm using omnifaces' [SelectItemsIndexConverter](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/converters/SelectItemsIndexConverter) here. It assumes the order of `categoriesList` stays constant during the page lifetime. Make sure to consult the documentation (or provide your own converter). You may also find the selectOneMenu [tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/selectonemenu/info) helpful.

Comment: I added CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE. But my problem still exist. I don't have any possibility to change category

Comment: I don't want change the category name in table Category. I only want to change film category for entity Film (I want change foreign key in Film table for category id)